# Differential Equation Theory

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose $x(t) , t \in (0, \infty)$ is a solution of the equation $\dot x=f(x)$. If  $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t)=x_0$ which $x_0\in \Re^{n}$. Show $f(x_0)=0$.

I tried to show if the slope of $x(t)$ doesn't vanish near the line $x=x_0$ then the $\lim x(t)\neq x_0$. But I don't feel it is the exact solution of this problem.

Comment: I think you mean "show  $f^{\prime}(x_0) = 0$."

Comment: no $f(x)=x_0$ which $f$ is the function that gives the slope of the solution of the differential equation at every point.

Comment: One could use $f(x_0)=f(\lim x(t))=\lim f(x(t))=\lim x'(t)=(\lim x(t) )'=(x_0)'=0$ but for this I need continuity of $f$ and uniform convergence of $x'(t)$.

Comment: Of course one should assume that $f$ is continuous, otherwise the value of $f(x_0)$ is irrelevant to the asymptotics of $x(t)$. To prove the result, note that if $f(x_0)\ne0$, there exists $i$, $c>0$ and a neighborhood $V$ of $x_0$, such that $f_i(x)\geqslant c$ for every $x$ in $V$ or $f_i(x)\leqslant-c$ for every $x$ in $V$. Now, $x(t)\to x_0$ hence $x(t)\in V$ for every $t$ large enough. Thus...